# What are the main vegan or vegetarian organizations in Latin America?

Tags: outreach

Yep, simple and straight-forward: Which are the main veg*n organizations, collectives, etc. in Latin America? In which countries does each organization work?

**Answer to the comments**. Since [Riker asks](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/525/what-are-the-main-vegn-organizations-in-latin-america?noredirect=1#comment907_525) for the meaning of **"main" word** I suggest to mean it as in the common language; so this would mean "more popular, bigger, most known, most active organizations, etc." Additionally a look on the [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/main) could be useful: "*chief in size, extent, or importance; principal; leading.*"

Comment: I think this is off-topic, as it's asking for a (possibly open-ended) list. And 'main' is a pretty subjective word, so it's partially opinion-based.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk I would say that by specifying the Latin America region the question is narrow enough to be answered effectively within the format encouraged on this site. While "list of" answers are frowned upon, this one likely won't be too long beacuse of the *main* keyword - which, while, as you say, subjective, can be easily understood as the ones with the biggest impact/member base, which will make the answers short enough to fit. As for the opinion-basedness, I believe that things like size of the member base are factual enough for not making the answers too much opinionated.

Comment: I'd like to see a better definition of 'main' then. Also, for the sake of future policy, I don't think we should allow even one.  I don't want to open the door for "Main Veg*n organizations in China", "Main Veg*n organizations in US", "Main Veg*n organizations in EU", etc.

Comment: @Riker While I understand your apprehension to that, veganism and vegetarianism can be individual as much as it can be collective, depending on one's viewpoint. People are likely to look for organizations that can connect them with like-minded people *in their vicinity* and look for *locally tailored* advice and activities. The way I see it, these questions are simply bound to arise and can either be constantly closed and unanswered or answered once and for all to benefit from. This could perhaps be a meta question to let community decide before public beta.

Comment: How does "veg*n" differ from "vegan"?

Comment: Veg*n is equivalent to say "vegan or vegetarian".

Answer (score 2):

[IAA - Instituto Abolicionista Animal](http://www.abolicionismoanimal.org.br/) (the Animal Abolitionism Institute) is the only organization based out of Brazil (that I know if) that is working to advance animal rights and encouraging dietary change.

The [Good Food Institute](https://www.gfi.org/) is a US-based organization advocating for plant-based meat, dairy, and egg substitutes which has a [director](http://vegnews.com/articles/page.do?pageId=9600&catId=1) stationed in Brazil.

And in Ecuador there is [La Revolución de la Cuchara](https://www.larevoluciondelacuchara.org/) ("The revolution of the spoon") promoting vegetarian and vegan lifestyles.

---

There are also a few non-vegan groups working on animal humane issues:

- [Humane Society International](http://www.hsi.org/) has a [chapter](http://www.hsi.org/world/latin_america/) operating in Latin America. They led the *Be Cruelty-Free* and *Meatless Monday* initiatives in Brazil.
- http://animalaware.org/en/
- [Proteção Animal Mundial](https://www.worldanimalprotection.org.br/) (World Animal Protection)

Answer (score 2):

Mercy For Animals, an international non-profit dedicated to protecting farmed animals, has recently branched out into Latin America and Brazil:

[Mercy For Animals Latin America](http://mercyforanimals.mx)

[Mercy For Animals Brazil](http://mercyforanimals.org.br)